# $_POST not working in PHP. have tried $_REQUEST also

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my HTML

```
   <form class="login-form" method="POST"> 
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password"/>
      <input type="button" id="login" name="login" value="login" onclick="redirect()"></input>
        </form>
```

And my JS

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function redirect(){
        $("#login").click(function(){
        var pwd="<?php echo $pwd?>";
        alert("<?php echo "this is pass".$pword?>");
        if(userID===user && pwd===pass)
        {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost/Annapoorna/Welcome_Page.php';
        }
        else
      {
         alert("Please enter correct username and password!");
      }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

And PHP

```
 <?php
     $username="";
     $pwd="";
     $pword="";
     function confirm(){


        if(isset($_REQUEST['password']))
        {
            $pword = $_REQUEST['password'];
        }

        $sth->execute(array(':pass'=>$pword));
        foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $row) {
        $username=$row['username'];
        $pwd=$row['password'];
        echo $pword;
        }
   ?>
```

$_POST is not returning any value. Have tried $_REQUEST, but didn't work. Have also assigned both ID and name to the password field.

Comment: `window.location.href = 'http://localhost/Annapoorna/Welcome_Page.php';` where are parameters? Either submit the form or add parameters to the URL. Not just redirect

Comment: Hey, page opens. So nothing wrong there.

Comment: Page will open, where is the parameter? you are not passing those

Comment: you need to pass parameters like :  `window.location.href = 'http://localhost/Annapoorna/Welcome_Page.php?id=123&password=test'`;

Comment: I don't need any. $_POST should return something in an alert box. Nothing to do with the next page.

Answer (score 1):

You are not submitting your form, just redirecting user to that page. Try this

```
<form id='myForm' class="login-form" method="POST" action='/Annapoorna/Welcome_Page.php'> 
  <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password"/>
  <input type="button" id="login" name="login" value="login" onclick="redirect()"></input>
    </form>
```

in your javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function redirect(){
    $("#login").click(function(){
    var pwd="<?php echo $pwd?>";
    alert("<?php echo "this is pass".$pword?>");
    if(userID===user && pwd===pass)
    {
     $('#myForm').submit();
    }
    else
  {
     alert("Please enter correct username and password!");
  }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: what is displayed in alert box?

Comment: I'm bothered about alert("<?php echo "this is pass".$pword?>");

Comment: Alert box had the text "this is pass"

Comment: you have to check for $pword in your code, as its not here in this snippet, also mark the answer as green if it did your job

Comment: Which code is it not there in? It's in both JS and PHP.

Comment: where you are getting value for $pword? its empty at the time of javascript runs

Comment: $pword = $_REQUEST['password'];

Comment: but for the first time there would not any value for $_REQUEST['password'] as user didn't submit the form yet

Comment: you need to fix flow for your page